# Flutter column is not expending and causing overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I think the  `Column` or `GridView` has fixed height and adding items to `Column` causes the overflow. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column myApp/lib/pages/bottomNavigation/profile.page.dart:439:22
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
```

**Code:**

```dart
class _ShopState extends State<_Shop> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.count( // error throwed from here 
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
          children: List.generate(12, (index) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                    'https://via.placeholder.com/150x105',
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 150,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      'Hair Brush',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[Text('\$90'), Text('asd')],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          })),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you may want to rephrase your question to include a question

Comment: Use childAspectRation (like 2/3) in GridView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Column` widget by default takes the maximum vertical space and since you provided `max` mainAxisAlignment, the children will be filled at maximum space available. Instead wrap the first widget inside `Column` with `Flexible` that takes the space as applicable to its child, so that rest of the children will be adjusted in remaining space, removing the overflow error. Working code below:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: GridView.count( // error throwed from here
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            crossAxisSpacing: 8,
            mainAxisSpacing: 4,
            children: List.generate(12, (index) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/150x105',
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 150,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                      child: Text(
                        'Hair Brush',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[Text('\$90'), Text('asd')],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })),
      )
    );
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the container of List.generate with a Expanded widget

Comment: It didn't work. I tried in different combinations but no luck.